# Python : Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have to use matplotlib and this is my first time using Python , so i found out that i have install numpy too .

I've came across with a lot of solutions for this problem but i guess problem depands on python version , 32bit to 64bit . I've tried everything for two days but nothing have worked yet.

```
**building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**
```

I'm using Pycharm 3.5 Community Edition 5.0.1

Python 3.5-3.2

win10 - x64

Also , i've seen something called "pip" , and i think pip installs .whl files if i want to install numpy or anything and i have no idea how that's work  .

I've installed visual C++ 2008 express edition with sp1 . (didn't worked)

Thanks for everyone's help !

Comment: You can get a wheel [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.10.2) too. Else, consider using pip, like `pip install numpy`. Should work!

Comment: Getting these libraries to compile on Windows can be quite fiddly. It might be much easier to download a distribution with the libraries already pre-compiled for your platform. [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) is a popular choice (other distributions are also available).

Comment: Pip doesn't work for a lot of Windows packages. You should download pre-made wheels from here or use Anaconda:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thanks i'll try that . with anaconda do i have to install anything or libs. come with it ?

Comment: All of Python's major scientific libraries (including NumPy and matplotlib) come with Anaconda; you just need to download and run the installer.

Comment: thank you for your effort , i have to tell , at first i really liked python but this problem make me crazy :D